# MAMP PRO won't shut down

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

After a recent update to macOS 10.13, one of the problems I face is MAMP PRO will not shut down. I can stop/start servers, but upon shutting down, it hangs indefinitely. Can anyone point me in the right direction? This is such a pain.

Comment: You were probably down voted as some would consider this the wrong place to ask about an Mac Application (which MAMP is).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue but just saw that a version 4.2.1 have been released. Now it's working for me.

[Download here](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/)

Comment: Fixed it for me too. Interestingly 'Check for Updates' on 4.2 didn't show that there was an updated available.